# Atualizar ficheiro .csv quando editado em Java

Tags: java, arquivo, csv

Tenho um ficheiro .csv que contem informação, mas quando removo informação (neste caso contatos) a partir da saída da consola o ficheiro .csv não está a ser atualizado. Como resolver?

```
    private void insertContact(String contactName) {
        contactsListModel.addElement(new Contact(contactName));
    }

    private void setContactsList() {
        contactsListModel = new DefaultListModel<Contact>();
        contactsList = new JList<Contact>(contactsListModel);
contactsList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
        contactsList.setLayoutOrientation(JList.VERTICAL);
        contactsList.setVisibleRowCount(-1);
        contactsList.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        loadContacts();

        add(contactsList, BorderLayout.CENTER);     
    }


    private void setContactsLabel() {
        contactsLabel = new JLabel("Contacts:");
        contactsLabel.setOpaque(true);
        contactsLabel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        add(contactsLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    }


        public void loadContacts(){

        BufferedReader br = null;
        String line = "";
        String separator = ";";

        try {

            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("diretorio"));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] contactName = line.split(separator);

                contactsListModel.addElement(new Contact(contactName[0]));

                System.out.println( );

            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (br != null) {
                try {
                    br.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
      }
}
```

Comment: O que é contactsListModel? Seu código parece estar incompleto.

Comment: private DefaultListModel<Contact> contactsListModel;

Comment: Mas de onde veio?

Comment: percebe agora??

Comment: Boa tarde, note que você postou apenas parte do código, tanto que a classe ButtonListener não esta inteira, falta fechar o `}`. Siga estas dicas  de http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve - Tenho certeza que vai levar meu comentário como uma critica construtiva.

Comment: essa classe buttonlistenner esta inteira sim, agora se esta correta não sei. obrigado! consegue me ajudar com a pergunta?

Answer (score 2):

Você criou um método que lê o arquivo e o transforma em uma lista de contatos. Quando você remove algo dessa lista, você está removendo apenas da lista. Isso é simplesmente esperado. Agora você precisa fazer um método análogo ao que carrega os contatos para salvar os contatos da lista num arquivo e chamá-lo quando alterar a lista. O jeito mais fácil é fazer um que recria o arquivo (apagando o que já existe) e imprimindo lá no arquivo um por um dos contatos. É importante manter o mesmo formato que você usa para leitura.

Comment: Como é o formato do seu arquivo?

Comment: o formato é numa coluna o nome na outra coluna da frente o numero (ficheiro .csv)

Comment: como faço isso em código? pode me dar uma ajuda?

Comment: Blz. Então basicamente você cria um BufferedWriter passando o endereço do seu arquivo como parâmetro e escreve nele uma string contendo o nome do contato, a vírgula e o número para cada elemento da lista usando um for. O BufferedWriter é quase idêntico ao BufferedReader, então não tem erro.

Comment: Eu atualizo quando chegar em casa.

Comment: muito obrigado pela ajuda vou ficar à espera, ate ja

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31121/discussion-between-java-and-pablo).

Comment: Consegue me ajudar?

Comment: Cheguei. Entre no chat, por favor.